# Edge with id already exists - Gremlin

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server, amazon-neptune

I am using the following to upsert an edge using Gremlin. I am following the recipe as mentioned [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#element-existence). This is the code I am using. The code runs in a lambda which talks to a cluster hosted in Amazon Neptune

```java
    public void createEdge(final String id, final String label, final String fromId, final String toId, final Map<String, String> properties) {
        this.graphTraversalSource
            .V(fromId) // get vertex of id given for the source
            .as("fromVertex") // label as fromVertex to be accessed later
            .V(toId) // get  vertex of id given for destination
            .coalesce( // evaluates the provided traversals in order and returns the first traversal that emits at least one element
                inE(label) // check incoming edge of label given
                    .has(T.id, id) // also check for incoming edge of given ID
                    .where( // conditional check to check if edge exists
                        outV() // get destination vertex of the edge to check
                            .as("fromVertex")), // against staged vertex
                addE(label) // add edge if not present
                    .property(T.id, id) // with given id
                    .from("fromVertex")) // from source vertexx
            .next(); // end traversal to commit to graph

        log.info("Created edge {} if it doesn't exists between {} and {}", id, fromId, toId);
    }
```

The only difference from the example recipe mentioned in the tinkerpop website is this step that I have added. In my case, I want to create multiple edges between the same vertices with same label but different ID

```
.has(T.id, id) // also check for incoming edge of given ID
```

But I am getting the following exception

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.ResponseException: 
{
    "detailedMessage": "Edge with id already exists: 123",
    "requestId": "dce46db8-1d0a-4717-a412-ee831973b177",
    "code": "ConstraintViolationException"
}
```

When I run the same query in gremlin console however, the experiment succeeds. The following query, how many times I execute, is returning the same edge. But the same is not happening with remote gremlin server

```
g.V().has('product','id','C1').as('v1').V().has('product','id','C2').coalesce(__.inE('rel').has('id', 'E1').where(outV().as('v1')), addE('rel').property('id', 'E1').from('v1')).next()
```

Can someone help me with this error

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The query that you have above (Lambda function code) and the query that you reference at the end of your question have one primary difference.  In the query at the end of your question:

```
g.V().has('product','id','C1').as('v1').
   V().has('product','id','C2').
      coalesce(
          __.inE('rel').has('id', 'E1').where(outV().as('v1')),  
          addE('rel').property('id', 'E1').from('v1')).
   next()
```

This query is using `has('id','E1')` to check the id of the edge, not `has(T.id,...)`.  `has('id'` is looking for a custom property called 'id', whereas `has(T.id` is looking at the actual edge ID.

Same goes for `property('id'`.  If using `(property('id'`, Neptune (specifically) is going to create a UUID for the T.id value for the edge when that edge is created.  So you'll end up with many edges with different T.ids but the same `id` property.

NOTE:  You only need to use the `T.id` notation when coding this in Python. If using the Gremlin console you would just use either `has(id,"myId")` or `property(id,"myId")`.  No quotes around `id`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using Gremlin-Java. Still unable to understand why `.has(T.id, id)` is not returning the edge. I am thinking because this is not returning any traversal, the code is taking the second branch of the `coalesce`. Is there a different way to check for `T.id` ?

Comment: There's also a `hasId()` step.  I would give that a try.

Comment: Thank you. It seems like my understanding about edgeIDs was wrong. I assumed any edgeID is unique from a source vertex to a destination vertex. But it appears IDs are unique across the graph

Comment: Correct. Edge IDs and Vertex IDs are globally unique within a given Neptune cluster.